# deep watch object with but get eslint warning

Tags: vue.js, vuex, eslint

I have object date , I want to deep watch object change , but I get warning

- warning  Unexpected unnamed method 'date.fontsize'                  func-names

how do I fix it?

```
watch: {
        "date.fontColor": function (val) {
            this.date.fontColor = val;
            this.$store.commit("setDate", this.date);
        },
        "date.datePosition": function (val) {
            this.date.datePosition = val;
            this.$store.commit("setDate", this.date);
        },
        "date.backgroundColor": function (val) {
            this.date.backgroundColor = val;
            this.$store.commit("setDate", this.date);
        },
        "date.fontsize": function (val) {
            this.date.fontsize = val;
            this.$store.commit("setDate", this.date);
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct syntax that preserves function names for debugging is:

```
["date.fontColor"](val) {
    this.date.fontColor = val;
    this.$store.commit("setDate", this.date);
},
```

Or:

```
"date.fontColor": function dateFontColor(val) {
    this.date.fontColor = val;
    this.$store.commit("setDate", this.date);
},
```

Comment: error    Unnecessarily computed property ["date.fontColor"] found  no-useless-computed-key

Comment: error    Expected longform method syntax for string literal keys   object-shorthand

Comment: To make it clear, these are linter errors, they shouldn't be equated to runtime errors. You get ESLint errors that are specific to your configuration, which contradicts itself. Linter rules can be disabled per need basis if they prevent you from writing code the way it should. You need to disable some of these rules to make it work as is. See relevant issue, https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12178 .

Comment: @EstusFlask Supplemented your comment about disabling ESLint with an answer talking about the Vue GUI as I feel it's an incredibly useful tool. Easy for beginners and very productive for experienced users

Comment: Thanks your answer ! this 2 way help me !

Answer (score 0):

To build upon the comment in the answer by Estus Flask, regarding ESLint errors, you can utilise the Vue CLI GUI to graphically manage ESLint rules.

Open up your terminal and run `vue ui` to start the interface.

Import your project if it isn't already and then navigate to the "configuration" tab.

Here you can find and disable the ESLint rule that is causing you issues without having to deal with the configuration files.

The Vue UI also has a bunch of other useful features such as build analysis, graphically configuring plugins and project settings, managing dependencies more intuitively, etc.

Comment: Thanks your answer!

Comment: No worries :) Glad you got it fixed